# How to choose article attributes in the frontend without any order?

Tags: magento-1.7

in the frontend of my shop customers first have to choose the color of an article and only then they are able to choose the size. But i want the free choice. :-) How can I set magento to that's regardless of which attribute my customers want to choose first?

Thanks in advance.

**<<<< EDIT >>>>**

Sorry, but i don't really know what additional informations you need, so that the question will not be marked as "too broad".

The problem in my shop is, for example, when a customer want to buy a T-Shirt he has to choose the color first and then he can choose the size. But I want him to do this also the other way around. So that he can choose the color or size first. At now, he is not able to choose the size before he chose the color.

I hope it's understandable what i mean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You know, you really don't want to have free choice -- as it is implemented right now size depends on color. Once you choose color, size dropdown is populated only with sizes available. Since sometimes not all size/color combinations are available, free choice option may cause a lot of frustration and guesswork.